# Printing message on the screen and also send to the syslog at the same time

Tags: linux, bash, logging, echo, syslog

I'm trying to implement `-s` (i.e. silent) option in my script - when given the Errors/Info etc, will be send to the syslog otherwise printing on the screen and also sending to the `syslog` at the same time. That's what I'm doing:

```
echo -e "This Is a Test Message\nWell, not really!!"  2>&1 | logger
```

to send the `echo` message to the `syslog` (which doesn't print on-screen) but couldn't just figure out how to do the both at the same time. I see people only talk about either logging with `syslog` or sending log  to a *different file* whilst printing on the screen but not the situation that I'm trying deal with. Any help or pointer would be greatly appreciated.  Cheers!!

Comment: you can pipe to `tee` : `... | tee -a /var/log/syslog`

Comment: Don't use `tee -a /var/log/syslog` - only root can do that, and syslogd might do all kinds of alternative handling other than just appending to that file.

Comment: @hek2mgl: True, but that file varies from system to system; e.g. `/var/log/messages` for Red Hat based system. Using `logger` is safer IMO. Cheers!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to send the message to syslog and to stdout (not stderr), you can do this too:

```
echo -e "This Is a Test Message\nWell, not really!!" | tee >(exec logger)
```

And the efficient way to do it (if you're creating a function):

```
exec 40> >(exec logger)

function log {
    echo -e "$1"
    echo -e "$1" >&40
}

log "something..."

exec 40>&-  ## optionally close it at the end of the script.
```

That would save your script from calling external binary logger everytime you do an echo.

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: @konsolebox: I think this is the way to go for me. So, just to mack sure, if I use custom file descriptor, there is no way to do it other than using the `echo` twice? cheers!!

Comment: @Juto: You call the function just the way konsolebox did: `log "Print something..."`. *log* is the name of the function.

Comment: You could also have tee: `exec 40> >(exec tee >(exec logger))`, though I'd still recommend just having one process for it. It's still the same anyway. Output is duplicated in tee.

Comment: But of course you're using another function to send output to `&40` and you only want to do it once, then the new method could apply.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, just echo the same message twice.  You can do:

```
echo -e "This Is a Test Message\nWell, not really!!" | tee /dev/stderr | logger
```

But, it's actually simpler and more efficient to do:

```
error='This Is a Test Message\nWell, not really!!'
echo -e "$error" >&2
echo -e "$error" | logger
```

The >&2 sends the output to stderr, rather than stdout.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
echo -e "This Is a Test Message\nWell, not really!!" | logger -s
```

The manual page (man logger) states:

```
-s     Log the message to standard error, as well as the system log.
```

Comment: Already tried `-s` but didn't like the fact that it prefixes the message with username: `admin: This Is a Test..."`. It also can't handle `\n` for the new line, which is not good for me. Cheers!!

Comment: I removed 2>&1 because it's essentially superfluous - it's not expected to have any effect here regardless of whether the -s option is used or not.